# Modular CSS Styles not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have created a boilerplate react app using `create-react-app`.

Now, In my `App.js` file

```
import classes from './App.css';
```

And I did

```
<div className={classes.App}>
      <Cockpit 
        showPersons = {this.state.showPersons}
        persons = {this.state.persons}
      />
      {persons}
</div>
```

But the syles are not getting applied.

My `App.css` looks pretty basic.

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
```

There are no errors in my console. 
I could not see any `webpack module config` file too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, show your App.css in your post above.

Comment: @Lynx Please see my updates.

Comment: import './App.css'; change your import to this

Comment: className={'App'} use your css class like this

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala That's the default one right. I am asking about the modular css styling which corresponds to a particular react component.

Comment: your code looks fine. try changing from text-align to background-color

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. 
To use modular CSS styling in react, you need to eject webpack config settings.